# How to add pagination in ReactTable with API call on click of next button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, pagination, material-ui, react-table

I want to add pagination with previous and next buttons in ReactTable where I am displaying 10 rows by default. I am not sure if there are more than 10 rows in the Database.

I want to first display the first 10 rows and on click of the next button, API should be called which will fetch the other 10 rows, if there.

Here's the ReactTable:

```
< ReactTable
columns = {
  [{
      Header: "Id",
      accessor: "id"
    },
    {
      Header: "Name",
      id: "name"
    }
  ]
}
manual
data = {
  data
}
pages = {
  pages
} < -- -- -- -- - I don 't know the total number of pages
loading = {
  loading
}
onFetchData = {
  () => this.fetchData()
}
/>
```

Here the problem is that I don't know the **Total number of rows** present in DB so that I can pass it to pages. How can I do that without knowing the total number of pages, and just simply clicking on the Next button if there are any rows, will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get total of element from your db

```
const DEFAULTPAGESIZE= 30
const total //from your bd
pagination={{
          defaultPageSize: DEFAULTPAGESIZE,
          total,
          onChange: page => {
            doChange(
              DEFAULTPAGESIZE,
              page * DEFAULTPAGESIZE - DEFAULTPAGESIZE
            )
          },
        }}
```

the advance should be like this:

```
doChange(limit, skip)
doChange(DEFAULTPAGESIZE, 1,2...n * DEFAULTPAGESIZE - DEFAULTPAGESIZE )
```

in math is:

```
1x30-30=0
2x30-30=30
3x30-30=60
```

Comment: I didn't get you. Do I need to know total number of rows in DB?

Comment: @shaluj yeah you need

Comment: I don't know the total number of rows.